# Android Thread for multiple semi-heavy operations

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, operations

I'm working on an application where I have a ListView and in some circumstances I want to update it every second. The reason I'm doing this is I want to tell the user how many seconds remained until a certaint event happens. I've set up a `CountDownTimer` which calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` once every second. This causes the `getView()` of my `ListAdapter` to be called. There I have this piece of code:

```
            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR, calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar1.get(Calendar.SECOND));

            int positionComp = pos + 1;
            int positionFix = (length - positionComp) + 1;

            String year = Resource.getSavedString(Integer.toString(positionFix) + Resource.KEY_YEAR, "0");
            String month = Resource.getSavedString(Integer.toString(positionFix) + Resource.KEY_MONTH, "0");
            String day = Resource.getSavedString(Integer.toString(positionFix) + Resource.KEY_DAY, "0");

            int yearI = Integer.parseInt(year);
            int monthI = Integer.parseInt(month);
            int dayI = Integer.parseInt(day);

            calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR, yearI);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthI);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayI);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
            long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();

            long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
            long diffDays = diffSeconds / (24 * 60 * 60);
            diffDays++;
```

This code can be called 15 times a second (in VERY extreme cases but it's still a posibility) which causes my `UIThread` to have some trouble accepting input.

The obvious answer to this would be to put the code in a Thread, but I have some questions first:
1. Should `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` be put into a Thread or should the long code with the calendars and the Longs be put into a Thread? I'm not sure if `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` will do the trick.
2. Since the code I'm using is fairly lightweight and problems only occur when it's called very often will be creating a Thread just slow it down because of the initializion time?
3. What sort of Thread should I use? I've read about them but they all seem to be for lengthy operations.

I really appreciate you reading this question and hopefully you can help me out. Leave a comment if there's anything you want to know more about or some more code you want to see.

Comment: did you use traceview to see what exactly takes up the largest amount of time ?

Comment: No I didn't. I haven't ever used traceview but I'll give it a go and report back. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: (chances are the actual drawing is heavier than the computation, in fact)

Comment: I didn't manage to get traceview working although I got the draw times. Drawing, meausuring and laying out took collectivly about 25ms for my layout with 6 ListItems. This shouldn't affect the UI Thread.

Comment: @njzk2 I forgot to mention you in the comment

Comment: 15 times 25ms is already 375 ms. in a second, that's not negligible. i would recommend trying to avoid refreshing 15 times. (may be get the time at some point, and reject any modification until some time later (may be 500ms later)

Comment: @njzk2 25ms is for 6 items meaning 15 items is about ~60ms. When I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the layout doesn't redraw if I remember correctly. Roman said that the ListAdapter reuses previously generated objects in some IO talk about ListViews.